# Assign permission set in a connected Org via external objects with Apex class

Tags: apex, permission-sets, externalobjects

We are creating users in a connected Org via external objects without issues, but when trying to assign the permission sets to those users we are getting the error "System.SObjectException: Relationship AssigneeId__r is not editable" in the putSObject method call.

The external object for the permission set assignment it's set to "Writable External Objects = true", but the fields are showing as read-only, with no option to modify this setting.

What I'm trying to figure out now is if this is possible at all (setting permition set assignment via extenal object) and if yes, if this issue is due to any problem on the way we used the putSObject method or if it is a matter of changing the external object fields to writeable.

Any help will be appreciated as I couldn't find any similar issue on previous posts.

Here is the code:

```
   public static void CreatePermissionSets(List<Train_User__x> userstoupdate, Train_User__x baseuser){
        List<Train_PermissionSetAssignment__x> insertassign = new List<Train_PermissionSetAssignment__x>();
        List<Train_PermissionSetAssignment__x> userassigns = [SELECT Id, PermissionSetId__c, AssigneeId__c FROM Train_PermissionSetAssignment__x WHERE AssigneeId__c =: baseuser.ExternalId];
        
        for(Train_User__x usertoupdate : userstoupdate){
            for(Train_PermissionSetAssignment__x userassign : userassigns){ 
                Train_PermissionSetAssignment__x newassign = new Train_PermissionSetAssignment__x();
                newassign.putSObject('AssigneeId__r', userassign);  //[43]|System.SObjectException: Relationship AssigneeId__r is not editable
//                newassign.putSObject('AssigneeId__r', usertoupdate);  
                insertassign.add(newassign);
            }
        }
        System.debug('Assignments to insert: '+insertassign.Size());
    }
```

Thanks